# Conseguir activar una rutina en "update" cuando haya una colisión en Unity con C#

Tags: c#, funciones, variables, unity

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

Un cubo1 choca con cubo2 y, al hacerlo, el cubo2 escapa hacia adelante indefinidamente.

El problema: solo avanza una unidad (que es lo que le indica hacer la función "adelante) pero me gustaría que la función "adelante" se repitiera frame a frame.

Decir que el choque de los cubos lo estoy haciendo manualmente con la herramienta arrastrar del editor.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimCubo : MonoBehaviour
{

      void Start()
    {


    }

     void Update()
    {

   //Me gustaría que se repitiera continuamente 
   la función adelante(); cuando hubiera una colisión con este objeto

}


void adelante()
{

    transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * 0.2f);

}




void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    //Check for a match with the specified name on any GameObject that collides with your GameObject
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Cube2")
    {
        adelante();
    }


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mí mismo por si a alguien le sirve, perdonad el formato aún no lo controlo. Simplemente podemos almacenar el resultado de oncollision en una variable y luego usarla como condición en el Update

```
  void Update()
    {
         { 
        if(variableAux == true)
            adelante();  
        {
    }  




 void adelante()
{

transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * 0.2f);

}




 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
 {
   //Check for a match with the specified name on any GameObject that collides with 
 your GameObject
  if (collision.gameObject.name == "Cube2")
   {
    variableAux = true;
   }


 }
```